# Stanford Sentiment Analysis is biased towards negative?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am doing some research into the existing sentiment analyzer apps. I am currently looking at Stanford CoreNlp/Sentiment Analysis 3.8.0 and what I noticed on my test data is the predictions seem to be biased towards the negative. Here are a few examples that come back Negative:

1. NY is where I ultimately want to spend my teaching career and the opportunity was too good to refuse. - Negative
2. I understand it is a duty to be an effective and influential teacher yet I am eager to put forth the hours before, during and after school hours to make certain I am an available resource to my students. - Negative
3. From my personal experience, I’ve learned many necessary life skills in the classroom and my most influential teachers were my motivators and supporters. - Negative

I checked and there is just one possible model to use (so I don't think there are any levers to push there - I don't want to train a model). I could use a different/better(maybe?) POS and that could give me a different prediction, but I am a bit mystified as all the blogs/comments I read about Stanford's library were positive and my results are so bad. Am I missing something?

The code:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    Annotation document = pipeline.process(text);
    pipeline.annotate(document);

    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
    int mainSentiment=0; int longest = 0;
    SimpleMatrix matrix = null;
    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
        String s_sentiment = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class);

        Tree tree = sentence
                .get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);
        int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);
        matrix = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictions(tree);

        System.out.println(sentence);
        System.out.println(sentiment + "-" +s_sentiment + "\t" + matrix.elementMaxAbs());
    }
```

Possible values for the scores:
0 Very Negative
1 Negative
2 Neutral
3 Positive
4 Very Positive

If you are using this library in a production application are you finding the results reliable to drive actions off of it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as of version [`3.3.1`](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html) there is not just one model to pass as an argument to [the option *sentiment.model*](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/sentiment.html#options) but rather two (sadly, this doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere on the site):

- A four-class model (*Very negative*, *Negative*, *Neutral*, *Positive*, *Very positive*) `edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz`
- A two-class model (*Negative*, *Neutral*, *Positive*) `edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.binary.ser.gz`

This is not part of the standard model set but rather [the additional `models-english` model](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html#download); In order to use it, you need to obtain it, which could be documented a bit better. The appropriate Maven artifact dependency would be

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>${stanford-corenlp.version}</version>
        <classifier>models-english</classifier>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

As described in [their 2013 paper](https://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RNTN.pdf), they used a corpus of movie reviews to create their model(s), and it's very possible that this data is sub-optimal for analyzing  the type of language you are: For example, [looking for *too good to refuse* in their corpus gives no results at all](https://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/treebank.html?w=too%2Cgood%2Cto%2Crefuse) despite it being a relatively common term.

I myself have also tried to use their pre-trained models to analyze conversational language with results that weren't bad but weren't amazing either: The accuracy of just creating a list of positive and negative patterns and looking for them in my texts was not significantly different from that of using the sentiment analyzer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am using version 3.8 and it doesn't recognize that path for the second model. I also cloned their repository and I don't see the second model anymore. Maybe they decided to get rid of it.

Comment: That's because it's not part of the standard model set; Please see my edit.

Comment: @Poc did this answer help you? If so, I'd be very appreciative of you [accepting and/or upvoting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).